# Find an derivatives value

Tags: derivatives

Please help me to determine a derivatives from the pic. Show me the way how to do it :), 
are that is trying to divide the value 1 ?,

I found it on Indonesian Language.

> Turunan pertama dari $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ adalah ....

Translation from Google:

> The first derivative of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ is ....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe they are asking to find the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$.

We can write $f(x)$ as $x^{-1/3}$

Applying basic derivative formula,

We get $f'(x)= \frac{-1}{3}x^{\frac{-4}{3}}$

In case you are wondering which formula I used, allow me to show you.

The formula is :

If $f(x)$ is a function equal to $x^n$, then it's first derivative with respect to $x$ is $nx^{n-1}$

Comment: Yeah of course dude, and please show your answer ;)

Comment: The answer is shown clearly. Please take a few minutes and patiently read everything.